# Netbeans Glassfish Autodeploy fails with GIT Revision in Maven's pom.xml <finalName>

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, glassfish

I'd like to build Jave EE .war files with the current GIT revision in their names. I managed to setup org.codehaus.mojo/buildnumber-maven-plugin and use
the following in my Maven pom.xml to generate proper target/*.war files:

```
<finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${buildNumber}</finalName>
```

Problem is: Netbeans 8.0.2 won't deploy the result in my local Glassfish 4.1, on "run" it just days:

```
NetBeans: Deploying on GlassFish Server 4.1
    profile mode: false
    debug mode: false
    force redeploy: true
```

There is no error or warning nor anything in Glassfish's sever.log.
The following line is missing in the Netbeans output though until I remove the ${buildNumber} again:

```
In-place deployment at /home/chammers/workspace/foo/target/Foo
```

I guess NetBeans does not read  but computes it itself and then does not find the proper directory in target/ and silently exists.

Any ideas?